# Assigning task to customer portal users

Tags: customer-portal, tasks

I want to assign a task to a customer portal user but it wont show up for selection. Do I need to enable something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can't assign tasks to Customer Portal users, though there [is a proposal on ideas to get this functionality added](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrFY).

You could just assign the tastk to the account for the user and then they should be able to see it when they login to the portal, but otherwise you're kinda stuck. If you need to make them specific to users you might be able to do something with a custom field to store the user's ID and then create a VF page which displays the relevant tasks to them.

Comment: okay, can I create a task using apex where logged in user is of customer portal type? What do you thing?

Comment: I've not tried, but given that it isn't available in the UI and such logic would be unlikely to reside in front end code, I expect the logic is performed at a low level and would be enforced for apex as well.

Comment: My understanding is this is intentional licensing restriction designed to get you to upgrade to the partner portal.  The idea being that assigning tasks (as well as working with opportunities and leads) is something a customer shouldn't need to do, but a partner would.